# Can @Output bubble up from component to parent if the parent is a module instead of a component?

Tags: angular

I'm working in an existing project, and need to send a message from one component to another. These two components are what I would call siblings. They share a common parent, but that parent is a module, not a component as I would expect. Right now I'm trying to figure out how to get an output to bubble up to the parent. If I can figure that out, I'm sure that I could figure out sending that message down to the other child component.

So far, I've got this added to the sending child:

```
  @Output() sendAction: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
```

I've added these two lines to the parent module (again, this is a module, not a component):

```
  @ViewChild(ReturnAuthorizationDetailComponent) detailComponent: ReturnAuthorizationDetailComponent;
  @ViewChild(ReturnAuthorizationItemComponent) itemComponent: ReturnAuthorizationDetailComponent;
```

I've added a method with a console.log to the parent module, but I haven't been able to figure out how to grab that emitted event and use it to call the method with the console.log.

Here's the module, with all the unrelated junk stripped out, and the couple lines that I've added so far.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [SharedModule],
  entryComponents: [
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    ReturnAuthorizationItemComponent,
    ReturnAuthorizationDetailComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    ReturnAuthorizationItemComponent,
    ReturnAuthorizationDetailComponent
  ],
})
export class ReturnAuthorizationsModule {
  @ViewChild(ReturnAuthorizationDetailComponent) detailComponent: ReturnAuthorizationDetailComponent;
  @ViewChild(ReturnAuthorizationItemComponent) itemComponent: ReturnAuthorizationDetailComponent;
  static itemComponent: any;
  static dynamicComp() {
    return {
      ngModule: ReturnAuthorizationsModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS,
          useValue: [
            ReturnAuthorizationDetailIndexListComponent,
            ReturnAuthorizationDetailRejectComponent,
            ReturnAuthorizationDetailReplaceComponent,
          ],
          multi: true,
        },
      ],
    };
  }
  
  ReturnAuthorizationItemComponentEmittedOutput() {
    console.log('ReturnAuthorizationItemComponentEmittedOutput');
  }
}
```

I have found lots of references for how to do this with a parent component, but not a parent module. The people who wrote this code are no longer with the company, so not sure why it is created this way.

Comment: I don't think it's possible and even if it is using a shared service between these components is a much better way.

Comment: Ah, that's a good idea. I should have thought of that. Thanks.